# Using Jquery to check the type of the element

Tags: jquery, html, select, typeof, prop

I mocked up some HTML to test this:

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<select id="options">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>one</option>
</select>
```

I was using the following JavaScript to alert the type of the select tag, but I kept getting false.

```
var elem = $("#text");
alert(elem.after().attr('id'));
```

I also tried using Jquery's `prop()` method but to no avail, I am just trying to check whether the element that follows the input tag is a select tag...

Comment: after() is for appending content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** since `select` is the immediate next sibling of your `input` with id `text`:

```
alert(elem.next().attr('id'));
```

Your code is not working because **[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** is used to

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the
>   set of matched elements.

Comment: wow...how did I miss that...I will mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use next instead of after() also you have to use `type` attribute to check if the next element is Select, use `prop` instead of `attr`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZG6Z/1/)**

```
alert(elem.next().prop('tagName') == 'SELECT');
```

Comment: typo? next) -> next()

Comment: Thanks @LShetty, so nice of you.